# Starting a Mono Process Programmatically

Tags: f#, mono

How can I start a process in mono using the Process.Start API? My best guess would be the following (in `F#`):

```
let start (path : string) = 
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/usr/bin/env", sprintf "mono \"%s\"" path)
```

This seems to work in linux, but it is obviously not correct in Mono/Windows. Is there any way I could obtain the location of the mono executable programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you can basically just `Process.Start` with just the target executable path, no need to specify the mono executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the location of Mono on windows using the following registry keys

```
$version = HKLM_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Novell\Mono\DefaultCLR
$monoprefix = HKLM_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Novell\Mono\$version\SdkInstallRoot
```

where you use the version you found to find the mono prefix.

Taken from [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Technical)

Comment: Thanks! Still, I would like to know if there is a platform-independent way to resolve the path.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than starting a new instance of the CLR, you can start assemblies from within your existing instance. Microsoft documents the relevant functionality here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk22e11a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Mono implements this as well.

What you have to do is create a new AppDomain to provide you with an execution environment isolated from your current one, load an assembly in there, and execute it.

Example:

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Foo");
domain.ExecuteAssembly("Bar.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was specifically looking for starting a separate process.